# Password generator in Java

Tags: java, passwords

I want a password generator in Java, which should generate passwords with standard criteria like  at least 8 characters long,contains one upper case letter, one special character etc.
It will great if it is open source. 
Any suggestions / pointers ?

Thanks.

Comment: don't forget to accept answers that have solved your problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I where you, I would put all allowed characters in a `char[]` and use [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) to select *n* characters from this array.

Once done, you could add digits and special characters until it fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I thought instead of reinventing the wheel I can use something which is already there.