# Password generation in Java

Tags: java, security

I want a password generator in Java using JAR file, which should meet standard password rules.
It would be great if it was open source. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Define "standard password rules".  Also, as per the FAQ, what research have you already put into this?  Did you Google "java password generator", for example?

Comment: There are no standard password rules. And if there were any, *Don't use a standard password generator* would be amongst them ;)

Comment: I think he needs something like combination numeric symbol and alphabet, minimum 8 chars.

Comment: @Andreas_D. I don't see why that would be bad.

Comment: like at least 8 characters long,contains one upper case letter, one special character etc.

Comment: @Andreas: why would that be? If it's well-implemented, then I think using a good password generator is probably *better* than forbidding its use (forcing people to revert back to guessable passwords).

Comment: @Joachim That depends on the implementation.  `public String generatePassword() { return "123456"; }` certainly returns a "standard password", according to most studies - and I wouldn't recommend using it! :)

Comment: @avs31586: Again, **there are no standard password rules**.  So saying "etc." in a list of your requirements is extremely unhelpful, both for us and for you.  It might do you good to think about, and write down, *exactly* what you want - it'll be much easier to find it that way.

Comment: @Kaj, @Joachim, general concern - if you know implementation details you *may* be able to generate the full value range (= all passwords). If generated passwords are random char sequences, it may be save. If the generator can produce *readable* passwords.. then I wouldn't us it (personally)

Comment: @Andrzej: Thanks for suggestion, standard rules means 8 characters long,contains one upper case letter, one special character etc. I agree with you. not a standard rule its a criteria

Comment: Is any open source jar file is available for  password generation?

Comment: @Andreas_D. Still don't see the point. Let us say that you instead have a page where you say "enter password, your password should be of at least X characters, and you should have ....". Then anyone can create a program that generates all possibilities, so you don't buy anything by not having the possibility to generate a safe password according to the rules. You just need to make sure that the generator isn't using a predictable seed. Remember that even encryption libraries are available with source code, and that doesn't make them less secure.

Comment: @Andreas_D: I understand that producing readable passwords (for example) reduces the effective key space. **But** that reduction buys you a higher chance that the password **won't** be written down, which can **easily** lead to a net *increase* in security (by reducing the risk of leaking the password, although its strength against brute force attacks is reduced).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

less than a month ago, someone asked the same thing: [Password generator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493884/password-generator-in-java)

this one is also very similar: [How can I create a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741160/how-can-i-create-a-password)

this one too: [Need a secure password generator recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090021/need-a-secure-password-generator-recommendation)

Some previous research is always good

Answer (score 1):

Try this : JPWGEN

http://hillert.blogspot.com/2008/09/jpwgen-password-generator-for-java.html

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final String charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
public static String getRandomPassword(int length) {
    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int pos = rand.nextInt(charset.length());
        sb.append(charset.charAt(pos));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: What about the uppercase letters ? And to assure that there's at least one uppercase, one digit, one downcase?

Answer (score 0):

Take a lool at [`Md5PasswordEncoder`](http://acegisecurity.org/acegi-security/apidocs/org/acegisecurity/providers/encoding/Md5PasswordEncoder.html) and [`PasswordEncoder`](http://www.acegisecurity.org/acegi-security/apidocs/org/acegisecurity/providers/encoding/class-use/PasswordEncoder.html) of acegi-security. And use it like:

```
public class SomeClass {

private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

// other code   

public String generatePassword() {
    byte[] ab = new byte[1];
    Random r = new Random();
    r.nextBytes(ab);
    return passwordEncoder.encodePassword(new String(ab), null).substring(24);
}
```

}